# Why is simple_form not creating my fields and creating hidden fields instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, simple-form

This is my ruby code:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@video, @video.comments.new]) do |f| %>
  <% f.association :comment_title %>
  <% f.input :body %>
  <% f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is the generated HTML markup:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/videos/485/comments" class="simple_form comment" id="new_comment" method="post">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="55xSU8JUe1SgipjAkAEvCvidFdJY3hv8Qz5VBqUSrdE=">
    </div>
    <input class="button" id="comment_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Comment">
</form>
```

Obviously it's not creating the :body input field and the association select list correctly. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Btw, a video has many comments, and a comment belongs to video. Also, a comment_title has many comments, and a comment belongs to a video. Comment_title is generated with virtual attributes.

Please let me know if there is any other code you would like to see.

Comment: Updated title to reflect body better

Answer (score 3):

Both of these are because of choices in your rails application.  The first is that you have selected to configure the application to use utf8 for character encoding.  The second is because by default the application is setup to protect against cross site request forgery attacks.  The authenticity token ensures that the response coming back to the server when the user submits the form is actually from you and not some other source just watching your traffic and posting away to mess with your database.

Comment: ahh ok, so could you please provide info on the potential options I have for getting around both of these issues?

Comment: Neither of them is an issue that you want to get around.  Is there a reason you don't want them there?  You could turn off the protections against cross site forgery requests, but I'm not sure why you'd want to.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the problem was that I needed to add the "=" to <%= in my form elements.

Comment: Accept this answer.